# How can I politely request a bounty to be placed on my question?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Apologies in advance if this question is boorish.

1. Is there something similar to Reddit's [/r/freegold/](https://old.reddit.com/r/freegold/) for bounties? [/r/FreeKarma4U](https://old.reddit.com/r/FreeKarma4U/) is less germane, as it's more alike to upvotes here.

Eg, my family and I are unskillful at computers and have many questions of   obvious public interest and benefit at Super User, but I don't have enough reputation to keep placing bounties.

2. Am I allowed to post on a SE's meta to request this?

Comment: Some users advertise their willingness to offer bounties in their [user profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/941965). Skim through that list and see how they prefer to be contacted if they are open for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @gnat I can't find where this specific question is answered in the FAQ ... apparently it's not asked frequently enough.

Answer (score 8):

> 1. Is there something similar to Reddit's /r/freegold/ for bounties?

No. Individual sites may have a [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243/38979) or a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/43020/bounty-room) dedicated to bounties; if you have a plan to regain reputation (see below), you could try posting your non-official bounty there.

> 2. Am I allowed to post on a SE's meta to request this?

You can try, but I guess such a post will be met with down- and close votes. E.g. here on Meta we have a close reason "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community."

> Eg, my family and I are unskillful at computers and have many questions of obvious public interest and benefit at Super User, but I don't have enough reputation to keep placing bounties.

Super User has a lot of posts which can be made better by grammar/spelling corrections and formatting improvements. If you restrict to suggesting edits on relatively new posts, I guess they will happily accept your edits; a bounty costs only 25 approved edits, and since you can gain 1000 reputation from suggested edits, that's enough fuel for 20 bounties.