# How can I see which users advertise their willingness to offer bounties in their user profile, ranked by their reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, bounties, data-explorer

[How can I politely request a bounty to be placed on my question? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319602/how-can-i-politely-request-a-bounty-to-be-placed-on-my-question)

> Some users advertise their willingness to offer bounties in their [user profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/941965). Skim through that list and see how they prefer to be contacted if they are open for that. – [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) [Dec 7 '18 at 8:13](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319602/how-can-i-politely-request-a-bounty-to-be-placed-on-my-question#comment1047277_319602)

How can I see the reputation of such users? Doubtless there's no point in requesting bounty from users with reputation of just 1.

Comment: Did you try clicking the "Run Query" button?

Comment: @animuson Thanks. That solved it! I asked a follow-up.

Comment: I made [a very similar SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1232508) today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all covered in the excellent [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/), so I'll add some steps and leave the rest as an exercise to the reader:

- [Fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/fork/941965) the query
- In the [database schema](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/intro-to-queries), you see the reputation is stored in the column `Reputation` in the `Users` table
- You can [add it to the list of selected columns](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/query-basics)

  - For bonus points, you can add a condition to the `WHERE` clause to filter on `Reputation >= 75`, since that is the privilege threshold
  - For additional bonus points, you can use the [`ORDER BY` clause](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/query-joins) to display the highest reputation first.

You should end up with something like this:

> ```
> select id as [User Link], reputation
> from users
> where aboutme like '%bounty%'
>   and reputation >= 75
> order by reputation desc
> ```